# C++ Program: Pizza Cost

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix the rest of the errors I'm getting with this code. I've changed and fix a lot of the errors but I'm stuck. I don't understand the syntax errors it's giving me. The syntax on the errors matched what we've learned in our textbook and the instructor's notes. 
The rules for the program are as follows: Define a class called Pizza that has member variables to track the type of pizza (deep dish, hand tossed, or pan) along with the size (small, medium, or large) and the number of pepperoni or cheese toppings. You can use constants to represent the type and size. Include mutator (set) and accessor (get)functions for your class. Create a void function, outputDescription( ), that outputs a textual description of the pizza object. Also include a function, computePrice(), that computes the cost of the pizza and returns it as a double according to the rules: Small pizza = $10 + $2 per topping, Medium pizza = $14 + $2 per topping, Large pizza = $17 + $2 per topping

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Source.h>

using namespace std;

const int DEEPDISH=1, HANDTOSSED=2, PAN=3;
const int SMALL=1, MEDIUM=2, LARGE=3;

class Pizza
{
public:
    Pizza();
    int getCrust(), getSize();
    double computePrice();
    bool getCheese(), getPepperoni();
    void outputDesription();
    void setCrust(int c);
    void setSize(int s);
    void setCheese(bool choice);
    void setPepperoni(bool choice);

private:
    int crust, size;
    bool toppingCheese, toppingPepperoni;
};

Pizza::Pizza()
{
    crust = DEEPDISH;
    size = SMALL;
    toppingCheese = toppingPepperoni = false;
}
int Pizza::getCrust()
{
    return crust;
}
int Pizza::getSize()
{
    return size;
}
bool Pizza::getCheese()
{
    return toppingCheese;
}
bool Pizza::getPepperoni()
{
    return toppingPepperoni;
}
void Pizza::setCrust(int c)
{
    crust = c;
}
void Pizza::setSize(int s)
{
    size = s;
}
void Pizza::setCheese(bool choice)
{
    toppingCheese = choice;
}
void Pizza::setPepperoni(bool choice)
{
    toppingCheese = choice;
}
switch (size)
{
case SMALL:
    cout << "Small ";
    break;
case MEDIUM:
    cout << "Medium ";
    break;
case LARGE:
    cout << "Large ";
        break;
default:
    cou << "Size not recognized";
    break;
}
switch (crust)
{
case DEEPDISH:
    cout << "Deepdish ";
    break;
case HANDTOSSED:
    cout << "Hand tossed ";
    break;
case PAN:
    cout << "Pan ";
    break;
default:
    cout << "Crust style unknown ";
    break;
}
double Pizza::computePrice()
{
    double cost = 0.0;

    switch (size)
    {
    case SMALL:
        cost += 10;
        break;
    case MEDIUM:
        cost += 14;
        break;
    case LARGE:
        cost += 17;
        break;
    }
    if (toppingCheese)
        cost += 2.0;
    if (toppingPepperoni)
        cost += 2.0;
    return cost;
}

int main()
{
    char crustStyle, pizzaSize, topping;
    int crust = 0, size = 0;

    cout << "What size pizza would you like (S/M/L): ";
    cin >> pizzaSize;
    cin.clear();

    switch (pizzaSize)
    {
    case 'S':
    case's':
        size = SMALL;
        break;
    case'M':
    case 'm':
        size = MEDIUM;
        break;
    case 'L':
    case 'l':
        size = LARGE;
        break;
    }
    {
        cout << "What style crust would you like ((D)eep dish/(H)and tossed/(P)an): ";
        cin >> crustStyle;
        cin.clear();
    }
    switch (crustStyle)
    {
    case'D':
    case'd':
        crust = DEEPDISH;
        break;
    case'H':
    case'h':
        crust = HANDTOSSED;
        break;
    case'P':
    case'p':
        crust = PAN;
        break;
    }
    int Pizza::custPizza();
    {
        custPizza.setSize(size);
        custPizza.setCrust(crust);

        cout << "Add cheese topping (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> topping;
        cin.clear();
        if (topping == 'Y' || topping == 'y')
            custPizza.setCheese(true);

        cout << "Add pepperoni (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> topping;
        cin.clear();
        if (topping == 'Y' || topping == 'y')
            custPizza.setPepperoni(true);

        cout << endl << "Your Pizza: ";
        custPizza.outputDescription();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Order total: $" << custPizza.computePrice() << endl;
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *fix the rest of the errors* What errors? You've not included a single error message or explaination of an *error* anywhere in your question or title. The title couldn't be much more vague, either. *Pizza cost* does not convey any information, and the C++ tag you added tells us it's a C++ question.

Comment: You can avoid the problem you're having with the code by making the selection a function.  Then all of that code that is intermingled in `main` (see the answer given to you) would be removed, and instead a `get_selection()` function would be called.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite! I'm sorry for the lack of information. I'm very new to Stackoverflow still figuring all the ins and outs. Thank you for the suggestion on how to make my posts for informative.

Comment: Hi @PaulMcKenzie! That makes so much more sense and would make it make the code look a lot cleaner. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yove' got a random pair of `switch` statements that are not within a function definition.  It's just random code wedged betweeen `setPepperoni` and `computePrice`.  Of course the compiler is going to complain.

```
void Pizza::setPepperoni(bool choice)
{
    toppingCheese = choice;
}
switch (size)                  // WHAT FUNCTION IS THIS STATEMENT IN?
{
case SMALL:
    cout << "Small ";
    break;
case MEDIUM:
    cout << "Medium ";
    break;
case LARGE:
    cout << "Large ";
    break;
default:
    cou << "Size not recognized";
    break;
}
switch (crust)              // THIS ONE TOO.
{
case DEEPDISH:
    cout << "Deepdish ";
    break;
case HANDTOSSED:
    cout << "Hand tossed ";
    break;
case PAN:
    cout << "Pan ";
    break;
default:
    cout << "Crust style unknown ";
    break;
}
double Pizza::computePrice()
{
    double cost = 0.0;

    switch (size)
    {
    case SMALL:
        cost += 10;
        break;
    case MEDIUM:
        cost += 14;
        break;
    case LARGE:
        cost += 17;
        break;
    }
    if (toppingCheese)
        cost += 2.0;
    if (toppingPepperoni)
        cost += 2.0;
    return cost;
}
```

Elsewhere in `main`, it appears you are trying to have a a function defintion withing a defintion.

```
case'p':
    crust = PAN;
    break;
}
int Pizza::custPizza();     // a new function defintion within main???
{
    custPizza.setSize(size);
    custPizza.setCrust(crust);
```

Comment: Thanks @Selbie! Yep, I definitely forgot the ouputDescription() function for those floating Switch statements. And nope that is not supposed to be a function definition at all. I feel stupid for not catching those. Thanks again for your help!